# kubeadm : unable to register node with api server x509 certificate signed by unknown authority kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I am trying to create a K8S cluster in HA. I have created 2 VMs, one acting as a load balancer and the second as the master node.

The load balancer has a simple NGINX server with the following configuration

```
events {}
http {
   upstream backend {
      server <master ip>:6443;
   }

   # This server accepts all traffic to port 80 and passes it to the upstream.
   # Notice that the upstream name and the proxy_pass need to match.

   server {
      listen 6443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/server.key;
      location / {
          proxy_pass https://backend;
      }
   }
}
```

the `server.crt` has been signed by my company CA certificate `ca.crt`

i copied `ca.crt` from the load balancer to the master node under `/usr/share/ca-certificates` and tried to `kubeadm init`

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --control-plane-endpoint <my-domain-name>
```

but kubeadm still doesn't recognize the CA cert. it displays

```
"Unable to register node with API server" err="Post \"https://<my-domain-name>:6443/api/v1/nodes\": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" node="master01"
```

any clues ? thanks

Comment: Hi khlilturki97 welcome to S.F. "the server.crt has been signed by my company CA" is not how kubernetes works; it has its own CA hierarchy and any x509 presented to the api-server must be signed by its CA. I'm sure it's possible to have the api-server be a leaf CA to your org's, but it's often more trouble than it's worth. That's a lot of words to say: you're solving the wrong problem, and should be just passing TLS traffic upstream in your HA setup, not trying to terminate TLS on the edge